# Explanation of the proof that SCAD penalty has the oracle property

Tags: mathematical-statistics, regularization, high-dimensional, oracle

I am trying to understand the proof that the SCAD has the oracle property. Could you help me with an explanation and a full break down of the steps, so that I can understand it?

I'm unclear on how exactly it is shown that SCAD has the oracle property. I'm new to the concept of oracle, and I don't understand the steps of the proof or how it was done. I was hoping to get an explanation on that or a break down of the proof. And if there are other alternative ways or easier ways to show it, i would be interested in learning about them.

I was referred to the original Fan and Li paper: https://fan.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf5476/files/documents/penlike.pdf

And this paper by Huang and Xie: arxiv.org/abs/0709.0863

this is the definition of oracle property:

An estimator $\hat{\beta}$ has the oracle property if there exists a sequence $\lambda_{\text{n}}$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\hat{\beta} = \hat{\beta}_{\text{O}}) = 1.$$

I'm new to this platform, before closing the question please specifically tell me what to improve in the question and provide me with the chance and some time to make the corrections. it's quite discouraging to see the question closed since i have been working on this problem for a while.

Comment: It is better to list the place or step where you got stuck.

Comment: @Zhanxiong i just didnt understand it and going between papers and online resources i'm a bit confused and unclear of it all

Comment: In minimal you should say what paper it is, and which theorem is in that paper.

Comment: I was referred to the original Fan and Li paper: https://fan.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf5476/files/documents/penlike.pdf

And this paper by Huang and Xie: https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0863

Comment: Hello. As Zhanxiong put in their words, you need to provide more details. I feel this question is salvageable but you need to tell what part you are not understanding.

Comment: i'm unclear on how exactly it is shown that SCAD has the oracle property. I don't understand the steps or how it was done and i was hoping to get an explanation on that or a break down of the proof

Comment: I see you need an explanation of the proof there. While I feel, a better specification of why you are not getting a part of the proof, it seems you need a breakdown of the whole proof for understanding. I am voting it to reopen.

Comment: @User1865345 thank you

Answer (score 4):

This answer is going to step through the two theorems of [Fan and Li 2001](https://fan.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf5476/files/documents/penlike.pdf). It will be helpful to already understand the asymptotic properties of MLEs, but I will try to describe everything in such a way that it is convincing even to someone who has not seen this.

Theorem 1 is analogous to the consistency of MLEs as it establishes a property very similar to root-n consistency (but including a contribution from the penalty term which will vanish by assumption).

Theorem 2 uses this consistency to show that the asymptotic distribution of suitable nonconcave penalties is similar to the asymptotic distribution of a regression using only the truly nonzero parameters. That's the oracle property.

***Notation***

We observe iid random variables $V_{i}, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.$ distributed according to the parameterized distribution $f(V_i, \beta)$ which satisfies  typical smoothness assumptions denoted by A-C of the appendix of Fan and Li. I will bring those up as needed rather than listing them beforehand. Let $\beta_0$ denote the true parameter vector. It will be broken up into $\beta_0 = [\beta_{0,1}, \beta_{0,2}]$ where $\beta_{0,1}$ is of size $s$ and contains the nonzero parameters (which are assumed to be the first ones in the vector just for notational simplicity; the algo does not exploit knowledge of this fact) and $\beta_{0,2} = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{d-s}$.

We denote $p_{\lambda_n}(|\theta|)$ as the penalty function which is applied to each element of $\beta$ and summed. The penalty is assumed to be a concave in $|\theta|$, differentiable for nonzero $\theta$ and $p_{\lambda_n}(0)=0$. We'll make some more assumptions as we need them.

The penalized log-likelihood is thus $Q(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(V_i,\beta) - \sum_{j=1}^d p_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_j|)$. We'll also denote the log likelihod as $l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(V_i,\beta)$.

When we say that $O_P(X) = f$, we mean that for all $\epsilon>0$, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N},\delta>0$ such that $\forall n>n_0$, it is the case that $P(\frac{X}{f} > \delta) < \epsilon$. We say that $\frac{X}{f}$ is *stochastically bounded*. Intuitively, for any probability we want, there is some constant $\delta$ such that eventually $X$ is less than that constant with the desired probability.

When we say that $o_P(X) = f$, we mean that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\to0} P(\big|\frac{X}{f}\big| \geq \epsilon) = 0$. We say that $\frac{X}{f}$ converges in probability to 0. Intuitively, as the sample size increases, $\frac{X}{f}$ becomes arbitrarily close to zero with arbitrary probability.

We will also be interested in the non-probabilistic version of little o notation. Here, $o(x) = g$ means that $\lim \frac{x}{g} \to 0$.

I will use this "o notation" because the authors do, but I won't assume the reader is familiar with it, and in particular, I will unpack "o notation" statements into simple inequalities the first time we encounter them.

Let's now begin.

***Theorem 1:***

i) Denote $\underset{\theta\neq0}{\max} p_{\lambda_n}'(|\theta|)$ by $a_n$. *[This is a bound on the contribution of the penalty term to the gradient of the penalized likelihood at any point except for zero. We omit zero because our penalties are not differentiable there.]*

ii) Denote $\underset{\theta\neq0}{\max} p_{\lambda_n}''(|\theta|)$ by $b_n$, and assume that $b_n\overset{n\to0}{\to}0$. *[Also limits contribution of penalty, this time to second derivatives.]*

Then there exists a local maximizer, call it $\hat\beta$, of $Q(\beta)$ such that:

$$
\Vert\hat\beta - \beta_0\Vert = O_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + a_n)
$$

***Proof***

Most of the ink in this proof is spilt to establish the following fact (**Equation A.1**), given an $\epsilon>0$ and a $C$ dependent on $\epsilon$:

$$
P\bigg(\underset{\Vert u\Vert=C}{\sup} Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) < Q(\beta_0)\bigg) \geq 1-\epsilon$$
$$
\implies
P\bigg(Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) < Q(\beta_0)\bigg) \geq 1-\epsilon \,\, \forall u \textrm{ such that } \Vert u\Vert = C
$$

where we have denoted $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+a_n$ by $\alpha_n$.
Let's put off proving this for now, and just think about what it would imply if we did.
The RHS of the inequality inside the probability is the value of the penalized likelihood at the true parameter vector $\beta_0$.
The LHS is the value of the penalized likelihood some distance $\alpha_n$ along the direction $u$ away from the optimum.
By allowing $u$ to be all vectors with norm $C$, we trace out a sphere of radius $C$ centered at the true parameter vector (the sphere is then rescaled by $\alpha_n$).
If it's true that $Q(\beta_0+\alpha_n u)<Q(\beta_0)$ for all such vectors, then it must be the case that there is a local optimum within the sphere (but not necessarily at $\beta_0$!).
Since the radius of the sphere is $C\alpha_n$, it is shrinking.
We thus have a sphere with shrinking radius within which we know are both 1) the true parameter value (by construction) and 2) a local optimum of $Q$ (with probability at least $1-\epsilon$).

In other words, $\Vert \hat\beta - \beta_0\Vert \leq C\alpha_n$, that $O_P(\Vert\hat\beta-\beta_0\Vert) = \alpha_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + a_n$.
We have not ruled out that other optima are outside this ball, nor even that the global optimum of $Q$ is outside this ball. But the proof is completed as originally proposed.

So that's that, but we still need to establish that that inequality holds in the first place.
To this end we will develop the expression:
$$
Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - Q(\beta_0)
=
\big[l(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - l(\beta_0)\big]
+
\big[\sum_j p(\beta_{0,j}+\alpha_n u_j) - p(\beta_{0,j}) \big]
$$

It's time to do some series expansions [(see this math SE question for that derivation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631055/multivariate-taylor-theorem-with-small-o-notation-not-continuous-only-differen).

Let's start with the ***likelihood***. We'll expand:

$$
l(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) = 
l(\beta_0) 
+ \alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
+ \frac{1}{2} \alpha_n^2 u^\top \nabla l (\beta_0) u
+ o(\Vert \alpha_n u \Vert^2)
$$

Now we need to define the information matrix
$$
I(\beta) = \mathbb{E}_{V\sim f_\beta}[-\nabla^2 \log f(\beta,V)]
$$
which is relevant to our expansion of the likelihood because
$$
\nabla^2 l(\beta_0) = \sum_{i=1}^n \nabla^2 \log f(\beta_0,V_i)
$$

So by the weak law of large numbers, it's true that:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \nabla^2 l(\beta_0) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \nabla^2 \log f(\beta_0,V_i) \overset{P}{\to} -I(\beta_0)
$$
Or in other words that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \nabla^2 l(\beta_0) + I(\beta_0) = o_P(1)
$$
meaning that we can write the matrix in the quadratic term of our series expansion as:
$$
\nabla^2 l(\beta_0) = n(o_P(1) - I(\beta_0))
$$

Such that:
$$
l(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - l(\beta_0)
= 
\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
+ \frac{1}{2} \alpha_n^2 u^\top n\big[o_P(1) - I(\beta_0)\big]u
+ \alpha_n ^2 \Vert u \Vert^2 o(1) 
=
\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
+ \frac{1}{2} \alpha_n^2 u^\top n\big[o_P(1) - I(\beta_0)\big]u
+ \alpha_n ^2 u^\top u o(1) 
$$
Let's fold that last term into the second:
$$
\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
+ \frac{1}{2} \alpha_n^2 u^\top n\big[o_P(1) - I(\beta_0) + \frac{1}{n} o(1) \big]u
$$

Since $o(\frac{1}{n}) = o_P(1)$, we can drop the $o(\frac{1}{n})$ term, leaving us with:

$$
l(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - l(\beta_0)
= 
\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
- \frac{1}{2} n \alpha_n^2 u^\top  I(\beta_0) u \big[ 1+o_P(1) \big]
$$

Now for the ***penalties***. Of course, for the truly zero parameters with indices $j>s$, it is the case that $p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j}) = 0$ by assumption.
$p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j} + \alpha_n u)$ is going to be some nonnegative number, allowing us to bound the contribution by just the nonzero terms:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j}+\alpha_n u) - p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j})
\leq
\sum_{i=1}^s p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j}+\alpha_n u) - p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j})
$$

I hope you didn't put the series expansion machine away because it's time to use it again. For each individual penalty on the truly nonzero parameters, expand:
$$
p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j}+\alpha_n u) - p_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{0,j})
=
\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2
+ o( \alpha_n^2 u_j^2)
$$
where $\textrm{sgn}$ is the sign function which just tells us what sign its argument is (and for our purposes needs only be defined on strictly positive or negative numbers).

Rearranging yields:
$$
\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2
+ \alpha_n^2 u_j^2 o(1)
$$
$$
=\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2 \big[1+\frac{1}{p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|)} o(1)\big]
$$
$$
=\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2 \big[1+o(1)\big]
$$

Let's take a moment to celebrate, because combining our likelihood and penalty expressions gives us ***Equation A.2***:

$$
Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - Q(\beta_0) 
\leq
\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
- \frac{1}{2} n \alpha_n^2 u^\top  I(\beta_0) u \big[ 1+o_P(1) \big]
+ \sum_{j=1}^s
\Bigg[
\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2 \big[1+o(1)\big]
\Bigg]
$$

Let's denote:
$$
A_1 = \alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0)^\top u
$$
$$
A_2 = - \frac{1}{2} n \alpha_n^2 u^\top  I(\beta_0) u \big[ 1+o_P(1) \big]
$$
and the whole penalty term by
$$
A_3 = \sum_{j=1}^s
\Bigg[
\alpha_n \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j
+
\frac{1}{2}\alpha_n^2 p''_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2 \big[1+o(1)\big]
\Bigg]
$$

such that $Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) - Q(\beta_0) 
\leq A_1 + A_2 + A_3$.

Since the information matrix is positive definite (by assumption), the $A_2$ term is going to be some negative number. The plan is to show that the magnitude of the $A_2$ term is bigger than that of the $A_1$ or $A_3$ terms such that their sum is a negative number, which would establish Equation A.1.

It's a commonly used fact that $\nabla l(\beta_0) = O_P(\sqrt{n})$. We can establish this by using the fact that, under standard assumptions, $\mathbb{E}[\nabla l(\beta_0)] = 0$ and $\mathbb{V}[\nabla(\beta_0)] = I(\beta_0)$ together with the Markov inequality applied on $\frac{\nabla l(\beta_0)}{\sqrt{n}}$ squared elementwise.

This means that $\alpha_n \nabla l(\beta_0) = \alpha_n\sqrt{n} \frac{\nabla l(\beta_0)}{\sqrt{n}} = O_P(\alpha_n\sqrt{n})$.

Since $\alpha_n\sqrt{n} = 1+\sqrt{n}a_n \geq 1$, we have that $\alpha_n^2n > \alpha_n\sqrt{n}$ and consequently that anything $O_P(\alpha_n\sqrt{n})$ is also $O_P(\alpha_n^2 n)$.

So $\frac{A_1}{\alpha_n^2 n} = O_P(1)$ and $\frac{B}{\alpha_n^2 n} = -\frac{1}{2} u^\top I(\beta_0)u(1+o_P(1))$.

Given a fixed epsilon, we thus know that $\exists M_\epsilon$ such that $\frac{A_1}{\alpha_n^2 n} < M_\epsilon$ with probability $1-\epsilon$.

We also know that $|\frac{A_2}{\alpha_n^2 n}| \geq \frac{1}{2} \Vert u \Vert_2^2 \lambda_1(1+o_P(1))$ where $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the information matrix, which is strictly positive by assumption. Recall that $\Vert u \Vert_2^2 = C^2$, so

$$
|2\frac{A_2}{\alpha_n^2 n}| \geq C^2 \lambda_1(I(\beta_0)+ C^2 o_P(1)
$$

but we also have that for all $n>n_0$, $|o_P(1)| < \frac{M_\epsilon}{C^2}$ where $M_\epsilon$ is the same constant as before. Thus:

$$
|\frac{A_2}{\alpha_n^2 n}| \geq \frac{C^2 \lambda_1 - M_\epsilon}{2}
$$

such that $\frac{1}{2}|A_2| > |A_1|$ if $C > \sqrt{\frac{3M_\epsilon}{\lambda_1}}$.

So we have established that $\frac{1}{2}|A_2| > |A_1|$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ if $C$ is sufficiently big.

Let's now attack $A_3$, considering for now the first term and recalling the definition of $a_n$,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^s n \alpha_n p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|) \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{j,0})u_j
=
 n \alpha_n a_n \sum_{i=1}^s \textrm{sgn}(\beta_{j,0})u_j
\leq 
 n \alpha_n a_n \sum_{i=1}^s |u_j|
\leq
n \alpha_n a_n \sqrt{s} \Vert u \Vert_2
$$

where we made us of the fact that $\Vert x \Vert_1 \leq \sqrt{s} \Vert x \Vert_2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^s$.

For the second part, we have:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^s n \alpha_n^2 p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta_{0,j}|) u_j^2(1+o(1))
\leq
n \alpha_n^2 \max_{\beta\neq0}p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta|) \Vert u \Vert_2^2 + \Vert u \Vert_2^2 o(\alpha_n^2)
$$

So we have that:

$$
|A_3| \leq
n \alpha_n a_n \sqrt{s} C + 
n \alpha_n^2 \max_{\beta\neq0}p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta|) C^2 +
 C^2 o(\alpha_n^2)
$$

For sufficiently large $C$, we can neglect the linear term in favor of the quadratic ones.
We see now why we had to make the assumption that $\max_{\beta\neq0}p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta|)\to 0$: so that we could write this as:

$$
\frac{|A_3|}{\alpha_n^2 n} \leq
 C^2 L
$$
where $\lim L = 0$.

Thus if we increase the sample size sufficiently, we also have that $\frac{|A_2|}{2} > |A_3|$.

Combining what we have so far, we get $|A_2| > |A_1| + |A_3|$ wp $1-\epsilon$. Hence, $\textrm{sgn}(A_1 + A_2 + A_3) = \textrm{sgn}(A_2) = -1$ with the same probability.

This establishes that $Q(\beta_0 + \alpha_n u) < Q(\beta_0)$ with probability $1-\epsilon$, completing the proof.

***Discussion of Theorem 1***

There isn't yet any penalty magic going on here. Actually, all we had to assume to establish thm 1 is that the penalty doesn't have too much influence. This result holds if the penalty is the zero function, that is, if it's absent. The purpose of Thm 1 is just to show that if you use a penalty that's sufficiently mild, we still get estimates that converge to the truth at the standard rate (assuming we can get find the right local max, that is).

Theorem 2 is where we actually start to establish some improvements offered by the penalties. It relies on the following lemma, which establishes that so long as we can estimate $\beta_{0,1}$ well, setting $\beta_{2}=0$ leads to a local optimum.

***Lemma 1***

Assume that
$$
\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf}
\underset{\theta\to0^+}{\liminf}
\frac{p_{\lambda_n}'(\theta)}{\lambda_n} > 0
$$
and that we pick $\lambda_n$ such that $\lambda_n\to 0$ but $\sqrt{n}\lambda_n\to\infty$.
Then for any estimator of the nonzero coefficients $\beta_1$ satisfying $\Vert\beta_1-\beta_{0,1}\Vert = O_P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, and any positive constant $C$, it is the case that:

$$
Q\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\ 
\mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg)
=
\underset{\beta_2\in\mathbb{R}^{d-s}}{\max}
Q\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\ 
\beta_2
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg)
$$

***Proof***

The strategy is to show that the $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta_j}$ is changes sign within some small $\epsilon$ of 0 for $j>s$, e.g.

$$
\frac{\partial Q(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j} < 0 \, \textrm{if} \beta_j \in (0,\epsilon)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial Q(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j} > 0 \, \textrm{if} \beta_j \in (-\epsilon,0)
$$

If the function was increasing arbitrarily shortly before getting to zero, and decreasing arbitrarily shortly thereafter, and it is continuous, it must have achieved a maximum at zero!

We'll again use a series expansion but now only on the likelihood and not on the penalty, and also now using the Lagrange form of the remainder:

$$
\frac{\partial Q(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j} = 
\frac{\partial L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j}+
\sum_{l=1}^d \frac{\partial^2 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})+
\sum_{l=1}^d\sum_{k=1}^d
 \frac{\partial^3 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l\beta_k}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})(\beta_k-\beta_{0,k})
-n p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_j|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_j)
$$

We're again going to be comparing magnitudes of terms, but this time we want the penalty term $A_2 := -n p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_j|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_j)$ to win out. Notice that $\textrm{sgn}(A_2) = -\textrm{sgn}(\beta_j)$, so if that term dominates the likelihood term, which we can call $A_1$, in magnitude, then it would determine the sign of the whole expression, and we would have established the results.

Thus we will in the remainder of this proof establish this fact, that $|A_1| < |A_2|$ with increasing probability as the sample size increases, by way of showing that $A_1 = O_P(\sqrt{n})$.

Let's break down $A_2$, labeling:

$$
B_1 = \frac{\partial L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j}
$$
$$
B_2 = \sum_{l=1}^d \frac{\partial^2 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})
$$
$$
B_3 = \sum_{l=1}^d\sum_{k=1}^d
 \frac{\partial^3 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l\beta_k}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})(\beta_k-\beta_{0,k})
$$

In the previous theorem, we established that $\frac{\nabla L(\beta_0)}{\sqrt{n}} = O_P(1)$, which implies that $B_1 = O_P(\sqrt{n})$.

The weak law of large numbers tells us that $\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l} 
= 
\mathbb{E}\big[
\frac{\partial^2 \log f(\beta_0, V)}{\partial \beta_j\partial \beta_l}\big] + o_P(1) = I(\beta_0)_{j,l} + o_P(1)
$.
This means that:
$$
|B_2| = |(I(\beta_0)(\beta-\beta_0))_j + o_P(1)|
\leq
\lambda_d \Vert\beta-\beta_0\Vert + o_P(1)
$$
where $\lambda_d$ is the max eigenvalue of the info matrix. Recall that $\beta_1 - \beta_{1,0} = O_P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ by assumption of the theorem and that we are considering $\beta_2$ within a shrinking $\epsilon_n = \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, such that $\Vert\beta-\beta_0\Vert = O_P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ as well. Since $O_P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})+o_P(1) = O_P(\sqrt{n})$, we thus have established that $B_2 = O_P(\sqrt{n})$.

To do the same for $B_3$ we will need to invoke a commonly made assumption in the asymptotics of likelihood based estimators, namely that:

$$
|\frac{\partial^3 \log f(\beta_0,V)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l\beta_k}|
\leq M_{i,j,k}(V)
$$

for some set of suitably functions $M_{i,j,k}$ arranged in a 3-way array each of which has finite expectation $m_{i,j,k}$. Denoting $m^*$ as the maximum of these over all $i,j,k$, this allows us to bound $B_3$ as follows:

$$
|B_3| = 
\Big|
\sum_{l=1}^d\sum_{k=1}^d
 \frac{\partial^3 L(\beta_0)}{\partial \beta_j\beta_l\beta_k}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})(\beta_k-\beta_{0,k})
\Big|
\leq
m^* \Vert\beta-\beta_0\Vert^2 + o_p(1) = O_P(\frac{1}{n}) + o_P(1) = O_P(\sqrt{n})
$$

(Note that $B_2$ and $B_3$ thus vanish much quicker than $B_1$ but we just need the $O_P(\sqrt{n})$ rate to establish the desired result.)

Therefore, we have that $A_1 = O_P(\sqrt{n})$. Now rejoining the authors, we can write:

$$
\frac{\partial Q(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j}
=
O_P(\sqrt{n})-n p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_j|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_j)
=
n\lambda_n\big[
O_P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\lambda_n})
- \frac{p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_j|)}{\lambda_n}\textrm{sgn}(\beta_j)
\big]
$$

We made the assumption $\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf}
\underset{\theta\to0^+}{\liminf}
\frac{p_{\lambda_n}'(\theta)}{\lambda_n} > 0$. Denote any positive lower bound by $\eta$.
With probability at least $1-\epsilon$, the $O_P$ term is below $\frac{M_\epsilon}{\lambda_n\sqrt{n}}$, which goes to zero by our assumption that $\lambda_n\sqrt{n}\to\infty$. So we need only choose an $n$ such that $\frac{M_\epsilon}{\lambda_n\sqrt{n}} < \eta$, and our result will be established.

***Discussion of Lemma 1***

This lemma now establishes some useful facts. First, it tells us that if we do a good enough job of estimating the nonzero parameters $\beta_{0,1}$, then setting the estimates of parameters which are actually 0 to 0 leads to a local maximum of the penalized likelihood, i.e. we will do a perfect job of estimating those parameters eventually. Theorem 2 will show us how this will also improve our estimates of the nonzero parameters.

We'll also note that it constrains our $\lambda_n$ sequence, which is helpful for practice. The prototypical sequence which respects $\lambda_n\to 0$ while $\sqrt{n}\lambda_n\to\infty$ is $\lambda_n = n^{-\frac{1}{4}}$.

***Theorem 2***

With probability tending to 1, there exists a local maximizer $\hat\beta$ of $Q$ such that:

1. $\hat\beta_2=0$
2. $\sqrt{n} 
   [I(\beta_0) + \Sigma)]
   \big[
   (\hat\beta_1-\beta_{1,0})
   + I(\beta_0) + \Sigma)^{-1} b
   \big]
   \overset{d}{\to} N(0,I(\beta_{0,1})
   $

where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal positive matrix and $b$ is a vector of size $s$, both to be defined.

***Proof***

(1) is established by Lemma 1.

For (2), Theorem 1 tells us that there is a local optimizer of $Q$ such that $\hat\beta-\beta_0 = O_P(\sqrt{N})$ if $a_n=0$ eventually. By Lemma 1, we can tell that this maximizer will eventually set $\beta_2 = 0$ with high probability. So let's think of this optimizer only in terms of its first $s$ nonzero components $\hat\beta_1$.

First order stationarity conditions tell us that the gradient vanishes at the optimum:

$$
\frac{\partial Q(\beta_1)}{\beta_j}\Big|_{\beta=\hat\beta} =
0 \, \, \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, s\} 
$$

We will now execute our final series expansion, on both parts of $Q$, reverting again to the Peano form of the remainder:

$$
0 = \frac{\partial Q(\beta_1)}{\beta_j}\Big|_{\beta=\hat\beta} =
\frac{\partial l(\beta_0)}{\beta_j} + 
\sum_{j=1}^s\frac{\partial^2 l(\beta_0)}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_l}(\beta_l-\beta_{0,l})
+ o(\Vert\beta_j-\beta_{0,j}\Vert)
- n p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,j}|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,j}) 
- n p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta_{0,j}|) (\beta_j-\beta_{0,j})
+ n o(\Vert\beta_j-\beta_{0,j}\Vert) \,\, \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, s\}
$$

We will again use the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \nabla^2 l(\beta_0) = I(\beta_0) + o_P(1)$, consolidate all little o terms, divide through by $\sqrt{n}$, and convert this equation to vector form, yielding:

$$
-\frac{\nabla_{\beta_1}  l(\beta_0)}{\sqrt{n}} = 
\sqrt{n} I(\beta_0)(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ \sqrt{n}b + \sqrt{n}\Sigma (\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ o_P(1)
$$

(Since $\sqrt{n}\Vert\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1}\Vert o_p(1) = O_P(1) o_P(1) = o_P(1)$).

where we have denoted:
$$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,1}|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,1})&
\ldots & 
p_{\lambda_n}'(|\beta_{0,s}|)\textrm{sgn}(\beta_{0,s})
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\Sigma = \textrm{diag}\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta_{0,1}|) & \ldots &
p_{\lambda_n}''(|\beta_{0,s}|)
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg)
$$

By the central limit theorem, $-\frac{\nabla_{\beta_1} l(\beta_0)}{\sqrt{n}} \overset{d}{\to} N(0, I(\beta_{0,1}))$, so the same must be true of the right hand side of the equation.

We now just need to get deal with the $o_P$ term. By Slutsky's, we have that

$$
\sqrt{n}\Big[I(\beta_0)(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ b + \Sigma (\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ o_P(1) \Big]\to 
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\sqrt{n}\Big[I(\beta_0)(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ b + \Sigma (\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
\Big] + 0
$$

such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\sqrt{n}\Big[I(\beta_0)(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
+ b + \Sigma (\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1})
\Big] = N(0, I(\beta_{0,1}))
$$

Rearranging the terms establishes the result as stated in the theorem.

***Discussion of Theorem 2***

The thing that differentiates this from standard MLE theory is that because $\hat\beta_2$ is clamped to zero by the penalty term, it doesn't contribute to the stationarity condition, and so we have fewer terms contribution to our gradient = 0 equation. This means that when we do a series expansion, there are fewer second order terms that contribute.

Theorem 2 implies that
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1}) \overset{d}{\to}
N\Big(\big(I(\beta_0)+\Sigma\big)^{-1}b,
\big(I(\beta_0)+\Sigma\big)^{-1}
I(\beta_0)
\big(I(\beta_0)+\Sigma\big)^{-1}
\Bigg)
$$

Neglecting contributions from the prior term (i.e. setting $b$ and $\Sigma$ to 0) would lead to:

$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta_1-\beta_{0,1}) \overset{d}{\to}
N\big(0,
I(\beta_0)^{-1}\big)
$$

That's really cool, because usually, if we were just doing MLE on the full space, we would expect to see not $I(\beta_{0,1})^{-1}$ (that is, the inverse of the first block of the fisher information), but rather the first $s$ rows and columns of $I(\beta_0)^{-1}$ (that is, the first block of the inverse of the entire fisher information). $I(\beta_{0,1})^{-1}$ is what we would get if we were doing MLE only on the $s$ truly nonzero variables.

This is why it's called the Oracle property: it almost acts asymptotically as if it knew what the truly nonzero parameters are (and it can do that because Lemma 1 tell us that those zero parameters will eventually be correctly estimated exactly as zero).